# How does one set the filename in Monodevelop?

Tags: mono

I have recently installed MonoDevelop V3.0.3.2 on Linux Mint 15 MATE 64-bit.
I installed MonoDevelop through the Software Manager

I attempted to create a new project per http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_A_Simple_Solution

Unfortunately I receive an error on attempting to build that the filename has not been set.  Details of error received are as follows.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: File name has not been set
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessWrapper.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessWrapper:Start ()
    at MonoDevelop.Platform.GnomePlatform.StartConsoleProcess (System.String command, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, System.String title, Boolean pauseWhenFinished) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessService.StartConsoleProcess (System.String command, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, IConsole console, System.EventHandler exited) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.SoftDebuggerEngine+<CreateDebuggerStartInfo>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__6 (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.BeginLaunch (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info, System.AsyncCallback callback, Mono.Debugger.Soft.LaunchOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.StartLaunching (Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerStartInfo dsi) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.OnRun (Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession+<Run>c__AnonStorey6.<>m__3 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How does one set the filename in Monodevelop?

EDIT: The Build of the project is working , Problem is occurring when attempting to run the application in the IDE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I found out that if you install xterm, and restart monodevelop the error will be resolved.  Apparently xterm is a dependency.  Just go to terminal and "sudo apt-get install xterm".

Comment: Went through so many tutorials and pages which did not result in a solution. Finally found your answer and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: sir, you are awesome!

Comment: wow, nice!  I have never had this problem with other linux distros but just ran into it using Loki - thanks man !!!